# Как экранировать одиночные кавычки в строчном литерале?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Kак экранировать одиночные кавычки в строчном литерале в PL/SQL блоке?

Пробую так:

```sql
stmt varchar2 (4000) := 'insert into mytable (col) values (\'ER0002\')';
```

, но это не работает.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11315340/6571020

Answer (score 6):

Используйте [альтернативное квотирование](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) с вводным символом `Q` или `q`:

```sql
stmt := q'[insert into MY_TBL (Col) values('ER0002')]';
```

Ограничителем может быть любой символ отличный от пробельных, и он же должен завершать литерал перед последней одиночной кавычкой. Исключение скобки - `{,(,[,<`, где в конце ожидается соответствующая закрывающаяся скобка.

---

Также, можно использовать две одиночные кавычки следующие друг за другом:

```sql
stmt := 'insert into MY_TBL (Col) values(''ER0002'')';
```

Но синтаксис квотирования с `Q` более гибкий и читабельный.

<sub>Источник: [@DCookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315369/6571020)</sub>